# CSS apply style on Html elements for a specific DIV ID

Tags: html, css

I have this css code but does not work as expected.

My aim is to applying attributes on tags: `table` `tbody` `tr` `td` on a **speific table only**.

Do you have an idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks for your help

```
#MainContent_uxTreeView table tbody tr td
{
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood your problem:

```
table#MainContent_uxTreeView tbody tr td
```

If you want the css to be applied to every tag from list, write them separated by comma:

```
#MainContent_uxTreeView table,
#MainContent_uxTreeView tr,
#MainContent_uxTreeView td
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you only need to do that on the table:

```
#MainContent_uxTreeView table
{
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
```

Side Note if you want to apply the same css rules to multiple selectors, seperate them with a comma

```
#main,#main1,#main2 {
   ...css rule ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an answer about similar issue.

[Load an external CSS for a specific DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7379168/load-an-external-css-for-a-specific-div/18252363#18252363)

You can only use the `applyCSSToHTML()`.

Good luck!