# Load an external CSS for a specific DIV

Tags: javascript, html, css

So basically I have a page that has it's own CSS. On my server I have a folder of different CSS style files, so I want to have a "preview" window on my page for them. Can I somehow, maybe using javascript, apply an external CSS file only to a certain DIV, not to the entire page so I can get a "preview" of the custom CSS file? I'd rather not use iframes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CSS applies to entire documents.

If you want to limit the scope, then you need to make use of a descendent selector.

e.g. `#id_of_div .the .rest .of .the .selector {}`

You have to apply this to every selector, and take into account [groups](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#grouping) (so it isn't as simple as just prefixing the whole stylesheet and  suffixing every `}`)

You would also find the stylesheet for the main document applying to your preview.

A frame would probably be the best approach to solving this problem.

Answer (score 11):

Like Quentin said, you can use descendent selector to limit the scope.  Something like [less](http://lesscss.org/) can help a lot.  For example, I would like to have "bootstrap.css" applies only to #MyDiv, in "my.less":

```
#MyDiv {
  @import "bootstrap.less";
}
```

"bootstrap.css" should be renamed (or linked) to "bootstrap.less". Run:

```
lessc my.less my.css
```

would add #MyDiv to every selectors in the imported file.

Comment: Can we do this using javascript?

Comment: @Jayanta you can use less.js to do this which means the render process is done in client side. It is not recommended on production usage though. See here for details http://lesscss.org/#client-side-usage.

Comment: shouldn't the @import rule always precede all other types of rules?

Comment: this is exactly what I needed.  I only wanted to apply the bootstrap classes to a specific div and this worked perfectly.

Comment: Is there a way to do this for selectors in the imported file that have commas?  The CSS you have would only take `.classA, .classB` and turn it into `#MyDiv .classA, .classB`

Answer (score 8):

For one of my projects, I needed exactly the same thing, but to be also supported in CSS version 2.
After a long search all over the web, I didn't found anything useful, so I decided to created this functionality using JavaScript that can actually able to apply a whole css to a specific Element in DOM.

Just call the function applyCSSFileToElement, as described below (depended on jQuery library):

```
function renderCSSForSelector(css, selector) {
    return ((css+"")||"").replace(/\n|\t/g, " ")
      .replace(/\s+/g, " ")
      .replace(/\s*\/\*.*?\*\/\s*/g, " ")
      .replace(/(^|\})(.*?)(\{)/g, function($0, $1, $2, $3) {
        var collector = [], parts = $2.split(",");
        for (var i in parts) {
            collector.push(selector + " " + parts[i].replace(/^\s*|\s*$/, ""));
        }
        return $1 + " " + collector.join(", ") + " " + $3;
    });
}

function applyCSSToElement(css, elementSelector) {
    $("head").append("<style type=\"text/css\">" + renderCSSForSelector(css, elementSelector) + "</style>");
}

function applyCSSFileToElement(cssUrl, elementSelector, callbackSuccess, callbackError) {
    callbackSuccess = callbackSuccess || function(){};
    callbackError = callbackError || function(){};
    $.ajax({
        url: cssUrl,
        dataType: "text/css",
        success: function(data) {
            applyCSSToElement(data, elementSelector);
            callbackSuccess();
        },
        error: function(jqXHR) {
            callbackError();
        }
    })
}
```

Functions explanations:

- **renderCSSForSelector** - Actually prepends a selector for each style definition.
- **applyCSSToElement** - Takes the CSS source data, applies renderCSSForSelector and injects it into the HEAD tag.
- **applyCSSFileToElement** - Applies a CSS file (*cssUrl*) into a specific area (*elementSelector*) in DOM. The *callbackSuccess* is called when the file is loaded successfully and the CSS has been applied. The *callbackError* is called when there is an error loading the CSS file.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You could use an iframe to load the preview page or dynamically load the CSS into the page. But, if you want the styles to only by applied to the div, you have to prefix your CSS selectors with the id of the div. `#div-id #element-inside-div { }`.

The script for loading it in might look something like this:

```
var cssFile = document.createElement( "link" );
cssFile.rel = "stylesheet";
cssFile.type = "text/css";
cssFIle.href = "file.css";
document.getElementsByTagName( "head" )[0].appendChild( cssFile );
```