# Restricting a css to an element and its descendants at runtime

Tags: css, angularjs

Today I am facing a problem of restricting the scope of css. The

```
<div class="parent">
<div id="childWithNoCss">
<p>No css</p>
</div>
<div id="childWithCss">
<p>Apply css</p>
</div>
</div>
```

My css is:

```
div{

color:red}

p{color:blue}
```

I need to apply the css specific to the id **childWithCss**. 
The css is fixed (I cannot change it) just need to limit its scope only to a specific element. 
I cannot use scope attribute since it is incompatible in some browsers. 
Is there any other solution?

Regards

Comment: What do you mean? That only the div with `id` childWithCss will applied that styles?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to find a workaround for this?

```
<style scoped>
  p { 
    //some style
  }
<style>
```

If so, there are some jQuery plugins that do the same thing and work for IE, at least for IE 9 and above. Here's one example:

[jQuery scoped CSS plugin](https://github.com/thingsinjars/jQuery-Scoped-CSS-plugin)

If that's not what you're trying to do, can you not just add some nested css? Does this help at all with what you are trying to do?

[Load an external CSS for a specific DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7379168/load-an-external-css-for-a-specific-div)

Comment: Your solution was what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the CSS of an element with the css code: `all:initial`.

You could use some javascript to do this at runtime for the elements you want to reset. I see you tagged your question with angularJS, so jquery should be available.

jquery solution to reset all css for the p in the divs WITHOUT `#childWithCss` within `.parent`:

```
$('.parent div:not(#childWithCss) p').css('all','initial')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2yXsL/3/

Comment: I cannot reset the css of an element the element may already contain a css of its own.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it with a bit of jquery

```
if ($('.parent').has('#childWithCss')) { 
    $('#childWithCss').find('p').css('color', 'red')
}
```

Comment: Works in this case bt what I was looking for was somefin more dynamic. I do not need a workaround to set the css but to just restrict its scope.

Answer (score 0):

Reset the color of everything except `#childWithCSS` to the default text color with a bit of jQuery.

```
$("p:not(#childWithCSS p)").css("color", "initial");
```